# Confusion about convolution

Tags: fourier-transform, dft, convolution, cross-correlation

I'm facing confusion about the definition of the convolution between two discrete periodic signals.

Basically, the definition of convolution between `s` and `t` is defined as :

[image]

In the operation, while the index of `s` is increasing (`[0, K-1]`), we have the index of `t` doing the opposite `[n, n-K+1]`.

But [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1352527) for example, the convolution is also employed, but the situation is different.  And from my understanding, convolution in this case could be defined as :

[image]

And now we can see that the indices of `s` and `t` are moving in the same direction and the result will be totally different if we compare it, with the first definition.

At this point, I'm hesitating between **convolution**, **circular/cyclic convolution**, or even **cross-correlation**. As a bonus, I'd be grateful if you could also clarify the difference between these terms.

Comment: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/82410/50076 The "computational" perspective the answer describes, also reflects CC's motivation (but not conv's). The reading it links (old, should say CH6) explains CC well, if CC is treated as a time-reversed kernel (valid for real-valued only)

Comment: Thanks, @OverLordGoldDragon. I'll go through it.